# Test to see if a file already exists

Tags: livecode

I have an iOS game, I am trying to save settings (which are generally stored within an array) to file.

currently,I have the file opened and read in the openStack handler; I have the file written in the shutdown handler...

but, in the openStack handler, how do I test to see if the file has actually been created... and if it doesn't exist I want to create one and write in some default settings

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I just open and read the file. Next, I put the contents into variables. If the contents happens to be empty, then I use a default value. This makes it unnecessary to check that the file exists and, more importantly, is more compatible with future versions of your software.

```
on readPrefs
  put specialFolderpath("documents") & "/prefs.dat" into myPath
  put url ("binfile:" & myPath) into myPrefs
  // here, the result may contain "can't open file"
  put line 1 of myPrefs into gHighscore
  if gHighScore is empty then put 0 into gHighscore
  put line 2 of myPrefs into gLicenseKey
  if gLicenseKey is empty then put "unregistered" into gLicenseKey
end readPrefs
```

You could also check for the file and use a slightly different script:

```
on readPrefs
  put specialFolderpath("documents") & "/prefs.dat" into myPath
  if there is a file myPath then
    put url ("binfile:" & myPath) into myPrefs
    put line 1 of myPrefs into gHighscore
    put line 2 of myPrefs into gLicenseKey
  end if
  if gHighScore is empty then put 0 into gHighscore
  if gLicenseKey is empty then put "unregistered" into gLicenseKey
end readPrefs
```

More variations are possible, e.g. you could check the result and set default values if the file can't be opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file already exists and if it does not exist you can put the default values into the file, which will then be created.
See below

```
if there is not a file "mysettings.dat" 
then put myDefaultsettings into URL "binfile:mysettings.dat"
```